# AutoPostBack and EnableViewState properties

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, autopostback

some of the asp.net server controls having for the above properties, but it is not  available for other controls, how it is determined if the GridView has above mentioned properties and the button doesnt?

Is it possible to add above properties to html controls if they runat="server" specified?

Answer (score 0):

You can not make Postback directly using the HTML tag. But still if you want to use HTML and want a postback then use javascript  by onchage() or __doPostBack().

Answer (score 0):

A button doesn't need an AutoPostBack property because clicking the button will cause a postback.  The most common place the AutoPostBack property is used is on the following asp.net controls: Drop down lists, checkboxes and radio buttons. Also, only asp.net controls (not html controls) participate in viewstate and so they are the only controls that have EnableViewState.